# Detect swipe without losing immediate response of tap

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gesture

I'm creating an Android game with Unity. There are only three ways to control the movement of the character:

- Tap in the right half of the screen: jump to the right
- Tap in the left half of the screen: jump to the left
- Swipe upwards: character dashes forward

In theory, I know that I can differentiate the touches with the TouchPhases (began, moved, stationary and ended). When only detecting the taps without caring for swipes, I just checked if the phase of the touch began and made the player jump. That felt fast on my device.

However, because I have to consider that a swipe may follow, I can not initiate the jump action until I detected ThouchPhase.Ended. This leads to a very slow responding character, which doesnt jump until the user rises his finger of the screen.

I tried to use ThouchPhase.Moved and ThouchPhase.Stationary instead to simulate a immediate response but my solution is pretty bad in terms of detecting the difference between a tap and a swipe:

```
Vector2 startTouchPosition;
Vector2 endTouchPosition;
Vector2 currentSwipe;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                //save began touch 2d point
                startTouchPosition = new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y);
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                //save ended touch 2d point
                endTouchPosition = new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y);

                if (endTouchPosition.y - startTouchPosition.y < 5)
                {
                    if (touch.position.x > (Screen.width / 2))
                    {
                        JumpToRight();
                    }
                    else if (touch.position.x < (Screen.width / 2))
                    {
                        JumpToLeft();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //create vector from the two points
                    currentSwipe = new Vector2(endTouchPosition.x - startTouchPosition.x, endTouchPosition.y - startTouchPosition.y);

                    //normalize the 2d vector
                    currentSwipe.Normalize();

                    //swipe upwards
                    if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
                    {
                        DashForward();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to implement something similar. I think you need the stationary case || with the began case. And put moved case || end together. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cant figure it out.. I set the startPosition in the began phase and jumped when phase was stationary. When the phase ended or moved, I checked if the distance between start- and endposition is greater a minimum distance and then executed the dash. Its still not reliable because the swipe sometimes seems to have a stationary phase in the beginning. then the player just jumps instead dashing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used. I tested and it works but sometimes, I noted a delay. Let me know if it is good enough for you. Basically you dont need to go through all touches if you dont need multi-touch. And you just need Begin and End touch phases.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class touch : MonoBehaviour {
private Vector2 startTouchPosition;
private Vector2 endTouchPosition;
private Vector2 currentSwipe;
public Text textbox;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {

        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            //save began touch 2d point
            startTouchPosition = new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y);
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            //save ended touch 2d point
            endTouchPosition = new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y);
            //create vector from the two points
            currentSwipe = new Vector2(endTouchPosition.x - startTouchPosition.x, endTouchPosition.y - startTouchPosition.y);

                //normalize the 2d vector
            currentSwipe.Normalize();
            if(Mathf.Abs(currentSwipe.y) < 0.1f && Mathf.Abs(currentSwipe.x) < 0.1f)
            {
                if (touch.position.x > (Screen.width / 2))
                {
                    textbox.text= "jump right";
                }
                else if (touch.position.x < (Screen.width / 2))
                {
                    textbox.text= "jump left";

                }
            }
            if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
            {
                textbox.text= "Dash forward";

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```